# Why is the hypotenuse of a triangle with length $\sqrt{2}$ finite even though its decimal expansion continues infinitely?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My answer:

We can represent the decimal part of the number as a sum of fractions.
$$\sqrt{2}=1.41421356237...$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ 1.41421356237...=1+\frac{4}{10}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{4}{1000}+\frac{2}{10000}+\frac{1}{100000}...$$
As you continue to add each term, the value of the each term added will get smaller since the numerator varies between 0 and 9 while the denominator gets exponentially larger. As the denominator approaches infinity, the value of the terms becomes negligible. For this reason, the $\sqrt{2}$ is finite in length.

Am I wrong? If so, where at? Also, are there better ways I could have phrased my answer? Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: How could $\sqrt2$ *not* be finite? Are there numbers which are infinite?

Comment: The summands get smaller quickly enough to ensure that the sum has a finite value. If this were not the case , only the numbers with terminating decimal expansion would have a finite value, not even $\frac{1}{3}$ would be finite.

Comment: $0<\sqrt{2}<2$ since $0<2<4$. Or you can say that if $\sqrt 2$ was not finite, its square, which is $2$, would probably be not finite either.

Comment: I agree your argument, although it could be made more formal. But important is that you understood what is going on and did not fall into a Zeno-like trap.

Answer (score 4):

The heart of your question is why the decimal part of any number, represented as an infinite series, converges. Note the generic geometric series converges:
$$1+r+r^2+...=\frac{1}{1-r},\quad |r|<1.$$

The decimal part of any number in base 10 as a series satisfies

$$0.a_1a_2a_3...=\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{100}+\frac{a_3}{1000}+...,\quad a_i\in \{0,1,...,9\}\\
\leq \frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\frac{9}{1000}+...\\
= \frac{9}{10}(1+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{100}+...)\\
= \frac{9/10}{1-1/10}=1.$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and referencing the geometric series. I didn't know that every decimal part of every number converged until now.

Comment: @anon1212 No prob. I guess it's sort of taught implicitly that the decimal part of a number is never greater than 1. Writing it as a series formalizes this claim.

Comment: @ryang How would you phrase it?

Comment: +1 to this distillation.

@anon1212 Your suggested argument (in the Question post) "the individual terms of an infinite series approaches zero, thus the series converges" isn't  valid; for example the series $\sum \frac1n$ diverges. [I'm critiquing the argument not the phrasing.]

Comment: @ryang Ah I see your point. Unfortunately, I do not have the mathematical experience to be able to modify my argument.

Comment: Yes, and that's why we're on MSE to learn. Welcome here! @anon1212

Comment: @ryang I interpreted the question rather as an understanding why the sum can be finite at all. You are of course right that it has to be justified that this reason actually leads to a finite sum. And this is excellently done in this answer. I upvoted as well.

Comment: @Peter Ah, I see what you meant.